# C Program - Receiving Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am still relatively new to C programming and have come across an error I haven't seen before. I have wrote a program that takes in two ints and converts the first into its respective form of radix based on the second input. I am not asking how to solve the problem I'm just asking where I went wrong to receive this error. I have done some research and know that segmentation faults have to do with pointers and I have played around with mine and have had no luck on getting rid of this error. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
    #include<stdio.h>

    void decimalToRadix(int d, int r, char *toRadix);   

    int main(void){

        int decimal, radix;
        char toRadixForm[100];

        printf("Enter a decimal number: ");
        scanf("%d",&decimal);

        printf("Enter radix number: ");
        scanf("%d",radix);

        decimalToRadix(decimal, radix, toRadixForm);
        puts("");
    return 0;
    }

    void decimalToRadix(int decimal, int radix, char *toRadix){

        int result;
        int i=1,x,temp;
        result=decimal;

        //will loop until result is equal to 0
        while(result!=0){

        //get the remainder
        temp=result%radix;

        //if<10 add 48 so character format stored values are from 0-9
        if(temp<10)
        temp=temp+48;

        //if greater that or equal to 10 add 55 to it stores values A-Z
        else
        temp=temp+55;

        toRadix[i++]=temp;
        result=result/radix;

     }
    printf("The value of the number you entered, %d, to radix form is ", decimal);

    for(x=i-1; x>0; x--){
       printf("%c", toRadix[x]);

}
```

Comment: The way to debug this (and most other bugs) is to use a debugger.

Comment: @kaylum I usually just step through it line by line when I get an error. Not too familiar with any debuggers so maybe I should re-word my original post. I appreciate your response.

Comment: Compare `scanf("%d",radix);` and `scanf("%d",&decimal);` carefully

Comment: @BLUEPIXY ah, I see where I may have gone wrong. Looks like I forgot an ampersand(&) after radix.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The reason you might be getting this is because of a typo i guess. You're missing a `&` in the scanf argument list on line 14. You should instead do : `scanf("%d",&radix);`. You were getting the Segmentation fault because scanf expects the memory address of the variable it is supposed to read; because it's the only way you can change a variable outside it's scope. But your're passing `scanf("%d", radix)` and in this case radix can contain 0 or any garbage value. When your program tries to access that memory address, which is not supposed to be read by the program, OS terminates the program giving [Segmentation Fault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346806/what-is-a-segmentation-fault). On changing this i was getting the output:

```
~/Documents/src : $ ./a.out 
Enter a decimal number: 12
Enter radix number: 2
The value of the number you entered, 12, to radix form is 1100
```

Comment: Thanks! @BLUEPIXY pointed that out above. Not sure how I forgot that and overlooked it but it obviously is necessary there for this program to run. I appreciate your response.